# GCP Container Builder unable to evaluate symlinks

Tags: google-container-registry, google-cloud-platform

Is Container Builder not able to handle Git Repos with symlinks?

```
Step #1 - "device-registry-php": unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /workspace/services/device-registry/build: no such file or directory
```

Comment: So far, every similar bug report we've seen has not been a Container Builder issue but rather an actual broken symlink. Can you please (1) confirm that your symlink is, in fact, valid; and (2) if it is valid, please provide me with instructions that will allow me to reproduce your issue. Thanks!

Comment: I think the root of the problem is I'm not understanding the Docker context.

I have a Dockerfile under `services/device-registry/base/build/docker/php/Dockerfile` but I want my build context to be `services/device-registry`

My Container Builder step looks like this:

https://gist.github.com/Simon-Ince/6caf5cb4943279c19afa41ba55c2d7df

And I get the error **unable to prepare context: The Dockerfile (/workspace/services/device-registry/base/build/docker/php/Dockerfile) must be within the build context (.)**

Comment: Can you please provide us with a complete reproducible case that we can look at? Without knowing the contents of these directories, I can't really tell what's going on even with the gist.

Comment: @david-bendory I've managed to get it working, I've changed it to - https://gist.github.com/Simon-Ince/e01835e920285dc45049d8a1e9573876

I didn't have to change the symlink so I'm not sure if it was a problem with the symlink or something else. This symlink has been working for others when cloning the repo, and in Jenkins, so I'm really not sure what the issue was...

Comment: Glad it's working!